# Error while converting mysql to sqlite

Tags: mysql, perl, sqlite

I have a perl script that converts Mysql dump to sqlite using the module 'SQL::Translator'.

Mysql file have following:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id1` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `text1` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `text2` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `text3` enum('N','Y') NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id1` (`id1`,`text1`,`text2`),
  CONSTRAINT `table1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id1`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

While converting it to final sql using 'SQL::Translator' module, I am getting following line in final sql:

```
CREATE INDEX "table1" ON "table2" ("table1");
```

when converting this final sql file to sqlite using **sqlite3** command, I am getting following error.

> there is already an index named table1 Error: near line 540: no such
>   table: main.table1

I have tried to remove the line `'CREATE INDEX "table1" ON "table2" ("table1");'` from final sql, then it worked fine.

PLease help

Comment: something looks inconsistent here. Can you please paste the scripts as is? Is `table1` actually the name of a column in your `table2`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this conversion? If it's for creating a test database then look at https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::mysqld  - SQLite isn't a great choice for using as a database, it'll ignore the FOREIGN KEY constraints for example

Answer (score 0):

Unlike MySQL, SQLite uses the same namespace for tables and indexes — you cannot have an index with the same name as a table. You'll need to change the name of the index.

Comment: How can we change the name of index?